# Public Dictionary in Unity

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

how I can make public Dictionary, what i use in other script and object in Unity? I have Dictionary in Object and script **A** and i want add values to this Dictionary with command in script/object **B**.

*For example A script in A object: *

```
public Dictionary<string, GameObject> dictio  = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
```

*For example B script in B object: *

A:

```
public Dictionary<string, GameObject> obstacleDictionary;

GameObject gob;

void Start()
{
    obstacleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
    pos = transform.position;

}
```

B:

```
Vector3 pos;
    public string openSide;
    GameObject player;
    string posString;
void Start ()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    pos = transform.position;
    posString = pos.x + "_" + pos.y;


    player.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().obstacleDictionary.Add(posString, gameObject); //warning

    //print(player.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().obstacleDictionary.ContainsKey("3_0"));
}

A.GetComponent<AScript>().dictio.Add("aaa", gameObject);
```

Can you help me? Thanks :)
[image]

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Code doesn't compile or any run time error?

Comment: Yes, there is my complete project with bug https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsCxyl5DQ6LHnXch-oX8HW2OaIx9

Comment: Can you please post the code and the problem in your question, thanks

Comment: @Valentin ok, i added code, but when you download unity project, you better understand what i mean :)

Comment: Error is on the picture

Comment: Line: `player.GetComponent<PlayerMove>().obstacleDictionary.Add(posString, gameObject); //warning`

Comment: Looks like `player` equals null or `player.GetComponent<PlayerMove>()` returns null, because it can't find this component.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I tried call some method on player.getcompo..... and it works, but when i want use dictionary, its problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't tell what doesn't work for you because you didn't mention what works or doesn't work. Here is a complete example:

Your `ScriptA` with public dictionary:

```
public class ScriptA : MonoBehaviour{
    public Dictionary<string, GameObject> dictio = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
}
```

You can access it from `ScriptB` with:

```
public class ScriptB : MonoBehaviour{

    ScriptA scriptInstance = null;  

    void Start()
    {
      GameObject tempObj = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectScriptAIsAttachedTo");
      scriptInstance = tempObj.GetComponent<ScriptA>();

      //Access dictio  variable from ScriptA
      scriptInstance.dictio.Add("aaa", gameObject);
    }
}
```

Make sure to replace `NameOfGameObjectScriptAIsAttachedTo` with the name of GameObject `ScriptA` is attached to.

**EDIT**:

Looked at your Project and found the problem. `obstacleDictionary` is being used from another script before being initialized in the `Start()` function..

Three ways to fix this:

In your PlayerMove.cs,

**1**.Replace `public Dictionary<string, GameObject> obstacleDictionary;`

with

`public Dictionary<string, GameObject> obstacleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();`.

then remove `obstacleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();` from the `Start()` function.

It should have worked if you followed my initial answer but you didn't. All you had to do was create the new instance outside the `Start()` function.

**2**.You can move `obstacleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();` from the `Start()` function to the `Awake()` function and it will still work.

Your new code:

```
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{

    Vector3 pos;
    public float speed;
    public static bool inside;
    public Dictionary<string, GameObject> obstacleDictionary;

    GameObject gob;

    void Awake()
    {
        obstacleDictionary = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
    }

    void Start()
    {
        pos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        gob = GetObjectAt(transform.position);
        if (gob == null) inside = false;
        else inside = true;
        print(inside);


        #region Control
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            GameObject go = GetObjectAt(transform.position - new Vector3(speed, 0, 0));
            if (go == null || go.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "right")
            {
                if (inside && gob.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "left") inside = false;
                /*if(inside && gob.CompareTag("BigRed") && go.CompareTag("BigRed")) { }
                else */
                pos.x -= speed;
            }
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            GameObject go = GetObjectAt(transform.position + new Vector3(speed, 0, 0));
            if (go == null || go.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "left")
            {
                if (inside && gob.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "right") inside = false;
                pos.x += speed;
            }
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            GameObject go = GetObjectAt(transform.position - new Vector3(0, speed, 0));
            if (go == null || go.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "up")
            {
                if (inside && gob.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "down") inside = false;
                pos.y -= speed;
            }
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            GameObject go = GetObjectAt(transform.position + new Vector3(0, speed, 0));
            if (go == null || go.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "down")
            {
                if (inside && gob.GetComponent<ObstacleMove>().openSide == "up") inside = false;
                pos.y += speed;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        transform.position = pos;

        if (inside && gob.transform.position != transform.position)
        {
            print("change");
            ChangeObstacleDictionary(gob.transform.position, transform.position);
            gob.transform.position = transform.position;

        }
    }

    public GameObject GetObjectAt(Vector3 position)
    {
        string pos = position.x + "_" + position.y;
        if (obstacleDictionary.ContainsKey(pos) == true)
        {
            print(obstacleDictionary[pos]);
            return obstacleDictionary[pos];
        }

        else return null;
    }

    public void ChangeObstacleDictionary(Vector3 lastPosition, Vector3 newPos)
    {

        string lastPosString = lastPosition.x + "_" + lastPosition.y;
        string newPosString = newPos.x + "_" + newPos.y;

        //print("test" + lastPosString + " " + newPosString);
        if (lastPosString != newPosString)
        {
            obstacleDictionary.Remove(lastPosString);
            obstacleDictionary.Add(newPosString, gob);
        }
    }

}
```

**3**.Change the **Execution Order** of your script and make `PlayerMove`  execute first before others. 
[image]

then

[image]

Comment: This is not work, there is my project, please check it https://1drv.ms/u/s!AsCxyl5DQ6LHnXch-oX8HW2OaIx9

Comment: @Adam You tried my solution under 1 minute? Great! Put some effort to get further help. Try it!

Comment: Because i tried it before you. All is in my project

Comment: @Adam Look at my Edit. You did not follow my initial answer. Provided 2 possible ways to fix this.

Comment: First I want to apologize that I didn't answer. I slept on keyboard. :D Thank you so much for your patience with me, it works. Which way is best? Is there any difference? Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Adam The first or the second one. I suggest you go with the first one. Don't do the last one. It should only be used as a last resort Don't forget to tick this answer if your problem is solved.