# Unity Object Pooling is Not Working When Scene Change or Refresh

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, object-pooling

I wrote an ObjectPooler code by watching [this Brackeys tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdSmKaJvCoA). It's working fine until I duplicate it to another scene. In the second scene when the scene changes or refreshes object pooler is not working anymore. It's spawning objects but doesn't bring objects and activate them.

Here is my ObjectPooler code:

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
        public class ObjectPool : MonoBehaviour
        {
            [System.Serializable]
            public class Pool
            {
                public string tag;
                public GameObject prefab;
                public int size;
            }
        
            public static ObjectPool Instance;
        
            public GameObject diamondCollectedFX;
        
            public List<Pool> pools;
            public Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>> poolDictinory;
        
            private void Awake()
            {
                Instance = this;
            }
        
            private void Start()
            {
               poolDictinory = new Dictionary<string, Queue<GameObject>>();
        
                foreach (Pool pool in pools)
                {
                    Queue<GameObject> objectPool = new Queue<GameObject>();
        
                    for (int i = 0; i < pool.size; i++)
                    {
                        GameObject obj = Instantiate(pool.prefab);
                        obj.SetActive(false);
                        objectPool.Enqueue(obj);
                    }
        
                    poolDictinory.Add(pool.tag, objectPool);
                }
            }
        
            public GameObject SpawnFromPool(string tag, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
            {
                if (!poolDictinory.ContainsKey(tag))
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Pool with tag" + tag + "Dosn't Excist");
                    return null;
                }
        
                GameObject objectToSpawn = poolDictinory[tag].Dequeue();
                objectToSpawn.SetActive(true);
                objectToSpawn.transform.position = position;
                objectToSpawn.transform.rotation = rotation;
        
                poolDictinory[tag].Enqueue(objectToSpawn);
                return objectToSpawn;
            }
        }
```

and this is my GameManager that calls ObjectPool for spawn objects:

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using TMPro;
    using Cinemachine;
    using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
    
    public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static GameManager Instance;
    
        [Header("About Health Variables")]
        private int health;
        public int collectedDiamonds;
        public int collectedCoins;
    
        public bool godMode;
        public bool gameStarted;
    
        [SerializeField] private float godModeDuration = 2f;
        [SerializeField] private float slowTimeDuration = 2f;
    
        [SerializeField] private GameObject healthObject;
        [SerializeField] private GameObject healthParentObject;
    
        [SerializeField] private GameObject menuCanvas;
        [SerializeField] private GameObject inGameCanvas;
        [SerializeField] private GameObject finishCanvas;
    
        [Header("About Level Progress")]
        [SerializeField] private Transform finishTransform;
        [SerializeField] private LevelProgressBarManager levelProgressBar;
        [SerializeField] private CinemachineVirtualCamera startCam;
        [SerializeField] private CinemachineVirtualCamera inGameCam;
    
        [Header("About Collectables")]
        [SerializeField] private GameObject diamondSprite;
        [SerializeField] private GameObject godModeIcon;
        [SerializeField] private TMP_Text diamondCountText;
        [SerializeField] private TMP_Text coinCountText;
    
        private float levelLength;
        private float remainDistanceToFinish;
    
        private float godModeTimer;
        private float slowTimeTimer;
    
        private int obstacleCount = 10;
        private int diamondCount = 3;
        private int coinCount = 25;
    
        private bool slowTimeBooster;
    
        private GameObject[] spawnPoints;
    
        private PlayerController playerController;
        private ObjectPool objectPool;
        private EconomyManager economyManager;
    
        void Awake()
        {
            Instance = this;
            playerController = GetComponent<PlayerController>();
            objectPool = ObjectPool.Instance;
            economyManager = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("EconomyManager").GetComponent<EconomyManager>();
            spawnPoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ObstacleSpawn");
    
            levelLength = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, finishTransform.position);
            diamondCountText.text = "0";
            coinCountText.text = "0";        
            
        }
    
        private void Start()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < obstacleCount; i++)
            {
                ObjectPool.Instance.SpawnFromPool("Obstacle", spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0,90,0));
            }
    
            for (int i = 0; i < diamondCount; i++)
            {
                ObjectPool.Instance.SpawnFromPool("Diamond", spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            }
            
            for (int i = 0; i < coinCount; i++)
            {
                ObjectPool.Instance.SpawnFromPool("Coin", spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            }
    
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                ObjectPool.Instance.SpawnFromPool("TimeSlower", spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                ObjectPool.Instance.SpawnFromPool("GodModeBooster", spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            }
    
        }
    
        void Update()
        {
            if (!gameStarted && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
            {
                gameStarted = true;
                startCam.Priority = 0;
    
                menuCanvas.SetActive(false);
                inGameCanvas.SetActive(true);
    
                for (int i = 0; i < economyManager.heartCount; i++)
                {
                    var heart = Instantiate(healthObject);
                    heart.transform.parent = healthParentObject.transform;
                }
                health = economyManager.heartCount;
            }
    
            remainDistanceToFinish = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, finishTransform.position);
            levelProgressBar.SetProgress(1 - (remainDistanceToFinish / levelLength));
    
            if (godMode)
            {
                godModeTimer += Time.deltaTime;
                if (godModeTimer > godModeDuration)
                {
                    godModeTimer = 0;
                    godModeIcon.SetActive(false);
                    godMode = false;
                }
            }
    
            if (slowTimeBooster)
            {
                slowTimeTimer += Time.deltaTime;
                if (slowTimeTimer >= slowTimeDuration)
                {
                    Time.timeScale = 1;
                    slowTimeTimer = 0;
                    slowTimeBooster = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Time.timeScale = 0.5f;
                }
            }
    
            if (health <= 0)
            {
                LevelFailed();
            }
        }
    
        void LevelFailed()
        {
            gameStarted = false;
            playerController.isGameStarted = false;
    
            GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Failed");
            startCam.Priority = 10;
            StartCoroutine(WaitForFailCanvas());
    
            inGameCanvas.SetActive(false);        
        }
        void LevelPassed()
        {
            gameStarted = false;
            playerController.isGameStarted = false;
            inGameCanvas.SetActive(false);       
    
            StartCoroutine(WaitForPassedCanvas());
        }
    
    
        private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
        {
            if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Diamond"))
            {
                other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                collectedDiamonds++;
    
                diamondCountText.text = collectedDiamonds.ToString();
                diamondCount--;
    
                while (diamondCount < 3)
                {
                    var selectedSpawn = spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position;
                    //if (remainDistanceToFinish < 15f)
                    //{
                    //    diamondCount = 3;
                    //}
                    if (selectedSpawn.z - transform.position.z > 10 || remainDistanceToFinish < 25f)
                    {
                        ObjectPool.Instance.SpawnFromPool("Diamond", spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1f,0), Quaternion.identity);
                        diamondCount++;
                    }
                }
    
                diamondSprite.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("DiamondCollected");
                ObjectPool.Instance.diamondCollectedFX.transform.position = other.transform.position;
                ObjectPool.Instance.diamondCollectedFX.SetActive(true);
            }
            else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Coin"))
            {
                other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                collectedCoins += economyManager.coinMultiplier;
                coinCount--;
    
                while (coinCount < 20)
                {
                    var selectedSpawn = spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position;
                    //if (remainDistanceToFinish < 15f)
                    //{
                    //    coinCount = 20;
                    //}
                    if (selectedSpawn.z - transform.position.z > 10 || remainDistanceToFinish < 25f)
                    {
                        ObjectPool.Instance.SpawnFromPool("Coin", spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position + new Vector3(0, 1f, 0), Quaternion.identity);
                        coinCount++;
                    }
                }
                coinCountText.text = collectedCoins.ToString();
            }
            else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Obstacle"))
            {
                other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                obstacleCount--;
    
                if (!godMode)
                {
                    health--;
                    Destroy(healthParentObject.transform.GetChild(healthParentObject.transform.childCount - 1).gameObject);
                }
    
                while (obstacleCount < 10)
                {
                    var selectedSpawn = spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position;
    
                    //if (remainDistanceToFinish < 15f)
                    //{
                    //    obstacleCount = 10;
                    //}
                    if (selectedSpawn.z - transform.position.z > 10 || remainDistanceToFinish < 25f)
                    {
                        ObjectPool.Instance.SpawnFromPool("Obstacle", spawnPoints[Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length)].transform.position, Quaternion.Euler(0, 90, 0));
                        obstacleCount++;
                    }
                }            
    
                if (health > 0)
                {
                    playerController.GetHitted();
                    godMode = true;
                }
            }
            else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Finish"))
            {
                startCam.Priority = 10;
                playerController.Finished();
                LevelPassed();
            }
            else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("TimeSlower"))
            {
                slowTimeBooster = true;
                other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            else if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("GodMode"))
            {
                godMode = true;
                godModeIcon.SetActive(true);
                other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    
        IEnumerator WaitForFailCanvas()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
            finishCanvas.SetActive(true);
            finishCanvas.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
        
        IEnumerator WaitForPassedCanvas()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
            finishCanvas.SetActive(true);
            finishCanvas.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

And the error is here:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yayyyy I found the solution! In any case, if this will be helpful for somebody [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901795/public-dictionary-in-unity) question has a solution for my problem guys! All I needed to change the execution order of my ObjectPool and GameManager script.

[image]